# mpv API : how to go to nth element in playlist?

Tags: api, playlist, mpv

I control mpv via socat on the terminal (bash script) like this :

```
echo '{ "command": ["playlist-next" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

and it works but I don't know the syntax to use for `playlist-pos`

```
echo '{ "command": ["playlist-pos", "100" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

gives the result :

```
{"error":"invalid parameter"}
```

how can I use this particular command/property and any help to make sense of the proper usage is much appreciated. thanks . I guess I didn't quite get **man mpv** manual .

Answer (score 0):

I found out the proper syntax to use :

```
 echo '{ "command": ["set_property", "playlist-pos", "100" ] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```